# Set/Modify Title in kendo mvc grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get hold of column bound info . so that i can add few settings(Width,Title etc) to Kendo grid where columns are created on fly .

**Code:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<dynamic>().Name("Grid").AutoBind(false) //model is dynamic
.Columns(columns => {
for (int index = 0; index < Model.mycolumns.Count; index++)
 { 
   var item = Model.mycolumns.ElementAt(index);
   columns.Bound(item.Value, item.Key).Title("Test").Filterable(false); // Title setting ignored 
 } 
});
```

when i set filterable false or Title to some value its ignored completely .

**Interestingly** when i comment complete `.columns(` bound code still i get to load grid with default settings and Title .

I have no control on grid settings (tough debugger fires) if i want to modify Title or freeze columns by applying lockable etc . whatever i write in cshtml under `bound` it's ignoring .

**Note** : mycolumns are of type `Dictionary<string, System.Type>` returning from controller on load